# Oracle Two similar tables in database - Different execution plans

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing, plsql, oracle12c

We have two similar tables in the database. The tables have the same DDL except for the table_name they also have similar indexed columns, statistics for both tables are re-gathered and index rebuild has been performed. The only differences between the tables are the data inside them (number of rows,values of rows,distinct values,etc). When we run our select query on the tables they both produce different explain plan. The one faster using INDEX RANGE SCAN (1 seconds). The one slower using INDEX FULL SCAN (completes within 1-3mins) a few days ago this is not the case on this table. Multiple INSERTS, UPDATES, and DELETES are happening on both tables daily. What are the things we can look into to replicate the issue?

Below is the explain plan for the table that has no issue

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                              |     1 |  5833 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                         |                              |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                                 |                              |     1 |  5833 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY               |                              |     1 |  1173 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| SABA_MESSAGES                |     1 |  1173 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | SABA_IDX_MESSAGES_PROCESS_ID |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Explain plan for the table that has issue (doing index full scan)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |             |     1 |  5833 |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                |             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                        |             |     2 | 11666 |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MESSAGES    |   108K|   104M|    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | MESSAGES_PK |   124 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


There are 3 existing index for these tables 
MESSAGES_PK ON MESSAGES ("ID") = Primary Key
IDX_MESSAGES_PROCESS_ID ON MESSAGES" ("PROCESS_ID")
IDX_MESSAGES_MESSAGE_TYPE" ON MESSAGES"("MESSAGE_TYPE") 

TABLE_NAME             NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS AVG_ROW_LEN STA
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---
MESSAGES                6705777     989842        1014 NO
SABA_MESSAGES           2721695     472871        1173 NO
```

Answer (score 0):

We won't be able to solve that for you, but can give you some pointers. Look at the Rows column on the TABLE ACCESS line. The top one expects 1 row. The bottom expects 108,000 rows. That's at least one reason why it chose a full scan (which benefits from more efficient "scattered" multiblock reads over sequential single-block reads). To determine why would require that we see the statistics and the predicate. There's an asterisk by #4 and #5 on the top, and also by #3 on the bottom. There should be predicate footnotes below keyed to these step numbers. That predicate information combined with stats from dba_tab_statistics and dba_tab_col_statistics is normally able to determine why the cardinality (ROWS column) estimate is what it is. Then there's the indexing - knowing what the index column list is in each case is also crucial. Whether the index needed is visible and in a usable state is also critical. If you are using bind variables, look at v$sql_bind_capture for your sqlid and get the value of the binds to see how that may be influencing it with bind peeking. Make sure the datatype of the bind matches the datatype of the leading column(s) of the index you hope it to use.

At the end of the day, if you can't solve the problem structurally or with stats, that's what hints are for. Just hint the query to do what you want it to do and be done with it:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(messages,IDX_MESSAGES_PROCESS_ID) */ -- or whatever the index is
  FROM messages
 WHERE ...
```

Of course, that will only work if the index is usable, visible, even remotely usable for your predicate, and the only problem is cardinality miscalculation.